# How to find hot questions for particular tag

Tags: discussion, support, hot-questions

There is an tab on Stack Overflow called [HOT](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot) with title displayed "Hottest Questions Today". where we can find today's hot filtered questions of SO.

My question is what to do if I want to find hot question of the day for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or any particular tag ?

Comment: Anyone?  Bueller? Bueller?

Answer (score 1):

lets say you want to search about "storm" as a

> "name of tag" (replace with desired tag like storm)

[Top hot questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/storm/hot)

> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/"name of tag"/hot

[Main entry page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/storm/info)

> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/"name of tag"/info

[Top users (askers or answerers) page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/storm/topusers)

> https://stackoverflow.com/tags/"name of tag"/topusers

[Featured page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storm?sort=featured&pageSize=50)

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/"name of tag"?sort=featured&pageSize=50

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/tags/storm/hot](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/storm/hot) Link shows hot answers not questions !!