# How can I find hot questions of the current day for a particular tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, hot-questions

Using this link: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/hot, I can find hot answers tagged with *android* of the current day.

How can I find hot *questions* of the current day for a particular tag?

I found this related post: [How to find hot questions for particular tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251752/how-to-find-hot-questions-for-particular-tag), but it did not help me.

I know, I can find questions with extreme votes via the [moderation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools), but this doesn't seem to work for a particular tag. And also, the tools are awarded when a [user reaches 10,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), so users below 10K reputation can't access them.

So my question are:

- Is there any way I can see hot questions of the current day for a particular tag?
- If not, can we add this feature?

**UPDATE**

With help of Luuklag's answer(advanced search) we can can find the hot *questions* of the current day for a particular tag

But can we request  the  feature of  hot *questions* same as [Hot answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/hot)

Comment: With hot questions for the day, do you mean A. Questions created today receiving a lot of votes, or B. Questions that received a lot of votes today, irrespective of their creation date?

Comment: If B is the case advanced search can help you out: Try this for MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a10-16-2018%20is%3aq and add a tag as desired

Comment: You can always sort by date

Comment: @Luuklag  hot questions means Questions created today receiving a lot of votes same as [Hot answers](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/hot)

Comment: Are you opted into the new question list? Not sure if this is restricted to that or not, but you could do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=MostPopular&filters=Today

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is an actual tab for this, but advanced search is your friend here:

For questions with the `[android]` tag, created today, sorted on votes you can use this hyperlink:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bandroid%5d%20is%3aq%20created%3a10-17-2018

- The `tab=votes` deals with the sorting on votes, high to low.
- The `%5bandroid%5d` is the android tag (`[android]`)
- The `is%3aq` is `is:q` to indicate that we are only interested in questions
- The `created%3a10-17-2018` is `created:10-17-2018` to indicate that we are interested in post created today (17th of October 2018)

For more advanced search options see [the advanced search help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Thanks for the info of  `advanced search`  But can we request the feature of hot questions same as Hot answers

Comment: If you want to make a good feature request I'd suggest you to make a new post, and leave this as discussion post. Also have a look on how to make a good feature request here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375365/how-do-i-constructively-propose-changes-to-stack-overflow-and-have-a-meaningful